# Python 3.x indexing and slicing

Tags: python-3.x

I have been confused with python indexing and slicing of data structure(lists,etc.). Let me explain the problem. Suppose I have a python list as shown below.

`examplelist = ['ram',  'everest' ,  'apple',  32,  'cat',  'covid',  'vaccine',  19]`

1. Example one

```
 >> examplelist[-5 : 7 : -1]

 >> [ ]
```

The result is empty set as shown above. Logic, explained in the python tutorial websites, I have checked is the starting count(-5) indicates item 32. End count 7 indicates one item before the stop/end count which is item 'vaccine'. Step size is -1 which means we need to move right to left. But since our starting item is 32 and end item is 'vaccine' there won't be any item if we move leftwards from 32. Hence the result empty list.  OK, agreed. Now lets see another example.

2. Example Two

```
>> examplelist[::-1]

>> [19, 'vaccine', 'covid', 'cat', 32, 'apple', 'everest', 'ram']
```

This is quite commonly used to reverse a list in python data structure. If we use the same logic provided for example 1, how can this example have a reversed list. Logically, with starting count 0(meaning start item is 'ram') and end count all the way until the end of the list and with step size -1 means here too we need to move leftwards from starting item i.e. 'ram'. This too has no items in it if we use the same logic. But this example seems to work differently. Why? Is it that reversing a list is an exception to the logic behind python indexing/slicing.

Now lets see another example below.

3. Example Three

```
>> examplelist[:-3:-1]

>> [19, 'vaccine']
```

In this example our starting count is 0 (so we begin at first item i.e. 'ram'), end count is -3 which refers to one item before the end count i.e. item 'cat'  and with step size -1 we move leftwards from start to end item. If we follow the logic there is no item to pick if we move leftwards from our starting item to end item. But the answer list is quite different.

My Confusion

I feel that there is no coherent logic working in all examples. Why does the same logic fails to different problem? My understanding it that there is always a standard logical explanation while coding. I tried to figure out some standard logic that will explain all types of indexing/slicing problem with python lists. But with examples listed above, my confusion still persists. Is it that there is a hole in my understanding or there is some standard explanation to this problem which I have not understood yet? Someone please rescue.

Answer (score 0):

Using a negative step reverses default start and end values for a slice.

These are all equal:

```py
examplelist[-5:7:-1]
examplelist[len(examplelist)-5 : 7 : -1]
examplelist[3 : 7 : -1]
```

And so are all these:

```py
examplelist[::-1]
examplelist[-1::-1]
examplelist[len(examplelist)-1 : -len(examplelist)-1 : -1]
examplelist[7 : -9 : -1]
```

As well as these:

```py
examplelist[:-3:-1]
examplelist[len(examplelist)-1 : -3 : -1]
examplelist[7 : 5 : -1]
```

Once you have positive start and end values, it becomes clear what is happening.

In the second example end value must be negative because there is no other way to represent the *element before the first element*.

Comment: OK. It seems the silver bullet was:  "Using negative step size reverses default start and end count".

Comment: @AK Yes, otherwise iteratively adding `step` to `start` could never get you to `end`.